# JPA with Eclipselink MySQL jdbc in Eclipse RAP/RCP

Tags: jpa, eclipse-rcp, eclipselink, classloader, persistence.xml

**System overview:**

- Eclipse Indigo for RAP RCP devs, RAP 1.4 Target Components, Dali JPA, Jre1.6.0_33 (Java1.6SE)
- local oracle mysql db
- all JPA (Persistence) + Eclipse link OSGi bundles imported in project (according to eclipse wiki)
- OSGi bundle containing com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class imported in project (latest 5.1.21 ? from Oracle page)
- persistence plugin created via JPA, with jdbc driver,correct mysql db path, correct password & user (added dependency to com.mysql.jdbc bundle)

**To avoid ClassLoader problem:**

- bundle/plugin ***com.mysql.jdbc*** has in its MANIFEST.MF: ***Bundle-BuddyPolicy: registered***
- ***org.eclipse.persistence.core*** & ***org.eclipse.persitence.jpa*** and mine ***"persistence bundle"***  having **Buddy** registered in their MANIFEST.MF : ***Eclipse-RegisterBuddy:com.mysql.jdbc*** + they have added dependency to this bundle com.mysql.jdbc

**Problem:**

even after all previous steps I have still:
`ClassNotFoundException - Driver not found`

**Remark:**

- connection to localhost mysql db tested from inside Eclipse DatabaseConnection, used same driver from bundle com.mysql.jdbc (class ***com.mysql.jdbc.Driver***) [OK]
- if ***org.apache.derby*** Embedded db with Embeded driver is used for persistence (instead of mysql) (with same Buddy policy), problem does not appear - everything works fine

**Question:**

- could it be problem still with ClassLoaders even if BuddyPolicy applied ?
- could it be problem in driver itselves, when its used as OSGi bundle ?
- has somebody ever try to use this com.mysql.osgi bundle in RCP or RAP together with JPA+Eclipselink ?

Answer (score 0):

I found problem in mysql.jdbc bundle which had no class path defined to JDBC class driver (My mistake, I probably overseen this)... I also checked PAX JPA and I think PAX JPA is not necessary now after I changed MYSQL JDBC bundle and Buddy Policy of OSGi bundles. I want to keep it simple: Equinox + Eclipselink JPA+JDBC driver.... I solved all issues now. and everythings works fine.